# How to replace umlauts in a string?

Tags: java, diacritics

Is there any good library that performs conversation of umlauts and special characters to their "flat" representation? Eg:

```
Ä -> AE
Ü -> UE
ß -> ss
```

Anything you could advise?

Comment: are you specific to German umaluts?

Comment: at the moment, yes. But later maybe also other languages.

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't it be Ä -> Ae, Ö -> Oe, ... Never saw the version with the e being capitalized. Also what is preventing you to use String.replace function? Like this `String replaced = "Ärmel Über Öffnung".replace("Ä", "Ae").replace("Ö", "Oe").replace("Ü", "Ue");`

Comment: You would use all-upercase AE when the whole word is capitalized (as found in headlines or emphasis)

Comment: See [Rename ä, ö, ü to ae, oe, ue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28943843)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `StringUtils`, This is not the well-known apache library . That is solve your issue.

```
replaceUmlauts

public static java.lang.String replaceUmlauts(java.lang.String string)

Replaces all umlauts in a string.
Umlaut  Replacement
ä   ae
ö   oe
ü   ue
ß   ss

Parameters:
    string - String, where the umlauts has to be replaced 
Returns:
    String without umlauts
```

Comment: I wouldn't trust that library to solve anything else than homework assignments.

Comment: It’s not even a library. It’s an application which happens to contain such a class. Nobody says that other people are allowed to use the class for other programs.