# Rename ä, ö, ü to ae, oe, ue

Tags: java, diacritics

We want to rename strings that way that "strange" characters like German umlauts are translated to their official non-umlaut representation. In Java, is there some function to convert such characters (AKA handle the mapping), not only for the German umlauts, but also for French, Czech or Scandinavian characters? The reason is to create a function that could rename files/directories that could be handled without problems on different platforms by Subversion.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420080/how-to-replace-umlauts-in-a-string) is similar but without a useful answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace umlauts in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420080/how-to-replace-umlauts-in-a-string)

Comment: Or a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234510/how-do-i-replace-a-character-in-a-string-in-java 
Could be either.

Comment: The ä does not correspond to ae, the ö does not correspond to the oe, and the ü does not correspond to ue. These are different characters. You may, however, translate them to regular (e.g ä -> a) by creating a map with the corresponding characters, checking if that character is in that map and if so replacing it.

Comment: The Scandinavian characters å,ä,ö,ø,æ are actually not umlauts, they are separate characters. So there is no such official translation.

Comment: The term for this operation is transliteration.

Comment: Umlaut is a misnomer. In this context it is just the German-originated name for the diacritic above the base character. The letters åäö can be expressed in Unicode as canonical decompositions of the base character and the diacritic.

Comment: @lacraig2: at least in German it is completely common to replace ä, ö, ü with ae, oe and ue if umlauts are not allowed or possible to enter, e.g. on a US keyboard.

Comment: @ThomasS. I'm not familiar with umlaut use in German, but from my admittedly limited experience it makes a difference in French.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Unicode block property `\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}` to remove (most) diacritical marks from Strings:

```
public String normalize(String input) {
  String output = Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD); 
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");

  return pattern.matcher(output).replaceAll("");
}
```

This will not replace German umlauts the way you desire, though. It will turn `ö` into `o`, `ä` into `a` and so on. But maybe that's okay for you, too.

Comment: Removing diacritical marks is not the same as transliteration.

Answer (score 5):

Use the ICU [Transliterator](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/Transliterator.html). It is a generic class for performing these kinds of transliterations. You may need to provide your own map.

Comment: Well, it's actually the mapping that I need.

Comment: Maybe you'll find one as a starting point here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-transliterate

Answer (score 3):

Answer is `Any-Latin; De-ASCII; Latin-ASCII;`

PHP specific answer using `Transliterator`  (sorry for not providing Java code)

```
$val = 'BEGIN..Ä..Ö..Ü..ä..ö..ü..ẞ..ß..END';
echo Transliterator::create('Any-Latin; De-ASCII; Latin-ASCII;')->transliterate($val);
// output
//    BEGIN..AE..OE..UE..ae..oe..ue..SS..ss..END
```

Normal ASCII rule is `Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII;` (`BEGIN..A..O..U..a..o..u..SS..ss..END`)

Rules should work in any language with support for [ICU](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu) = International Components for Unicode.